# How to change file names in Shell Script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a task to rename a bunch of files to their content at row1 colum2 (a string). The files do not have extensions. I also have to add .pdb as an extension to every file.

so far I've written this and it does not work :(

```
#! /bin/bash
for f in sequences/*; do
mv "$f" "($ awk 'NR==1 {print=$2}').pdb";
done
```

I am very very new to Shell script and still have no idea how to use it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a homework problem

Comment: Yes it is homework though the lecturer did nor provide any examples or material how to even select files, use awk, or pretty much do anything :)

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem releated to Ubuntu (maybe you are running ubuntu but this is not a problem with Ubuntu but it is a problem with bash scripting) , I don't think that this will be well-answered on this website, So post your question on [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (BTW this question is on topic)

Comment: Is this university problem or hs problem? Just asking..

Comment: I know this is opinion and not shared by everyone … but what’s wrong with a homework question when the OP has gone to some effort to solve it? I don’t want to do people’s homework for them, but for me it’s ok to help if they’ve tried.

Comment: That's a university problem.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

1. the syntax for command substitution is `$( command )` not `($ command )`
2. the syntax for printing the second field in awk is `print $2` not `print=$2`
3. you need to pass the name of the file as an argument to awk ex. `awk 'NR==1 {print $2}' "$f"`

Also note that the new file will be created relative to the current directory, rather than the subdirectory `sequences` (there's not enough detail in your question to know whether that's the intended outcome or not).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you steeldriver! The remarks helped a lot! The 3rd one was the real problem solver! So here's the script I wrote in the end:

```
#! /bin/bash
for f in $(ls); do
mv "$f" "$( awk 'NR==1 {print $2}' "$f" ).pdb";
done
```

If anyone has any 'smarter' ways of doing it I would be very happy to hear them.

Thanks!

Comment: `f in $(ls)` makes no sense ;-)

Comment: It might not make sense but it did the job and that's the best I can do currently. If you have smarter ways, you are welcome to enlighten the inferior being with your large brain ;-)